# Android: Options Menu as Drop-down Navigation in ActionBar

Tags: android

I created an Options menu like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item   android:id="@+id/menu_mark"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_q1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_fertig"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_q2"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

and

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_q1:
        ...
```

now I want to use the menu items that are not show in the action bar directly in a ActionBar Spinner Drop-down Navigation. 
I use the sample code but dont't know how to let mSpinnerAdapter take the menu entries and 
mOnNavigationListener handle item clicks. Thanks

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
```

Comment: This was asked a few times before

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this:
[Dropdown Spinner outside of actionbar? (IceCream Sandwich style, w/ActionBarSherlock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323471/dropdown-spinner-outside-of-actionbar-icecream-sandwich-style-w-actionbarsher)

This is an example with the Sherlock Actionbar

Comment: didnt help too much because he doesnt use a menu and so on