# Manually open ActionBar navigation list

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBarSherlock with navigation mode set to NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and an adapter for it. The list shows up as expected.

The drop-down list appears when the user presses the item in the ActionBar, but I also need to be able to make the drop-down list appear when the user presses a hardware key (the menu key). I know how to get the key event but I can't seem to find any call to open the drop-down.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using the native `ActionBar` implementation. The `Spinner` that's placed in the `ActionBar`, when you're using that particular navigation type, is created in code. Because there's no special ID to reference, you couldn't call something like `Spinner.performClick`.

Alternatively, you could inflate a custom layout for your `ActionBar` with a `Spinner`, override the Menu button, and call `Spinner.performClick` when that is pressed.

**References**

[ActionBarView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L720)

[Spinner.performClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#performClick%28%29)

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion does the job perfectly well.
I used the IcsSpinner from ActionBarSherlock as the spinner in a custom layout to get the same drop-down effect, and it opens up when performClick() is called.

[IcsSpinner from ActionBarSherlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810289/ics-spinner-drop-down-rather-than-dialog-in-older-android-versions?lq=1)