# ICS spinner outside ActionBar and not working dropdown menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, spinner

I've tried to make IcsSpinner outside ActionBar using ActionBarSherlock. I used the informations from [Dropdown Spinner outside of actionbar? (IceCream Sandwich style, w/ActionBarSherlock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323471/dropdown-spinner-outside-of-actionbar-icecream-sandwich-style-w-actionbarsher). It looks nice, that's what I am looking for. My problem is that my spinner shows only first option and is not clickable. Dropdown menu is not accessible and method getDropDownView is never called.

HoloSpinner.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner;

public class HoloSpinner extends IcsSpinner {

  public HoloSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, com.actionbarsherlock.R.attr.actionDropDownStyle);
  }

 public HoloSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }
}
```

HoloSpinnerAdapter.java:

```
package pl.tmmk.organizer.studencki;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HoloSpinnerAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> implements SpinnerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private T[] array;

public HoloSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int res, T[] objects){
    super(context, res, objects);
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    array = objects;
}

@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("HINT", "getView");
    final TextView filterName;
    if (convertView == null) {
      filterName = (TextView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, parent, false);
    } else {
      filterName = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    filterName.setText(getItem(position).toString());
    return filterName;
  }

  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      Log.d("HINT", "getDropDownView");
    final TextView filterName;
    if (convertView == null) {
      filterName = (TextView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
      filterName.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
    } else {
      filterName = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    filterName.setText(getItem(position).toString());
    return filterName;
  }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return array.length;
}

@Override
public T getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return array[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

part of xml file:

```
<com.xxx.yyyy.zzzzz.HoloSpinner
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:id="@+id/event_type_spinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:background="@drawable/abs__spinner_ab_holo_dark"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

spinner initializing:

```
String[] eventTypeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.event_type_array);
HoloSpinnerAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new HoloSpinnerAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, eventTypeArray);
HoloSpinner spinner = (HoloSpinner) findViewById(R.id.event_type_spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

My goal is obtaining ICS look like spinner even on older Android version phone. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's IMPORTANT to set the **style** in the manifest like

```
<activity android:name="fr.example.demo.MyActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"></activity>
```

or to modify the theme style in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
</style>
```